# setTimeout without polluting global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

Consider the following javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var private_function = function(){
    alert("private_function!");
  }

  setTimeout("private_function();", 1000);  

});
```

This yields the error "private_function is not defined".

Is there a way to defer execution of a private / anonymous function in javascript without polluting the global namespace / exposing it via a global module?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  var private_function = function(){
    alert("private_function!");
  }

  setTimeout(private_function, 1000);  

});
```

**OR**

```
$(function(){
  var private_function = function(){
    alert("private_function!");
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    private_function(); // with this method you can also pass some arguments
  }, 1000);  

});
```

Comment: simple `setTimeout(private_function, 1000);` w/o quotes should work too, no?

Comment: Yep, I gave two solutions ;), look at the first one. But I also gave the second solution in case he needs to pass some arguments to its callback function. Also sometime the first method can't work, for example when you want to use a different scope with `apply` or `call`

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout(private_function, 1000);` to set the Timeouthandler to the function.